# How to ensure that my program prints the supplied values, not incorrect values?

Tags: c++, c++14

Why my program is printing incorrect values, not the supplied values? Any help would be much appreciated.

**Data**

```
title1=q, year1=1, title2=w, year2=2
```

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
    
    
int getnumber ();

struct movies_t {
  string title;
  int year;
};

void printmovie (movies_t films);

int main ()
{
    
  int z=getnumber ();
  cout << "You will have to provide data for " << z << " films.\n";
  
  //movies_t films [z];
  vector<movies_t> films(z);
    
  string mystr;
  int n;

  for (n=0; n<z; n++)
  {
    cout << "Enter title: ";
    getline (cin,films[n].title);
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter year: ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    cin.ignore();
    stringstream(mystr) >> films[n].year;
    
  }

  cout << "\nYou have entered these movies:\n";
  for (n=0; n<z; n++)
    printmovie (films[n]);
  return 0;
}

void printmovie (movies_t films)
{
  movies_t * pmovie;
  pmovie = &films;

  cout << pmovie->title;
  cout << " (" << films.year << ")\n";
}

int getnumber ()
{
  int i;
  cout << "Please enter number of films: ";
  cin >> i;
  return i;
}
```

**Output (obtained; incorrect)**

```
Please enter number of films: 2
You will have to provide data for 2 films.
Enter title: q
Enter year: 1
Enter title: w
Enter year: 2

You have entered these movies:
 (0)
 (0)
```

**Output (desired)**

```
Please enter number of films: 2
You will have to provide data for 2 films.
Enter title: q
Enter year: 1
Enter title: w
Enter year: 2

You have entered these movies:
 q (1)
 w (2)
```

Comment: In each iteration of the loop, you set the film's year twice... I assume that's a mistake... `movies_t films [z];` is also not valid in c++

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: the `cin.ignore()` after `std::getline` will throw away the first character of the next line, as you are only entering a single character the line will be empty

Comment: `movies_t films [z];` Change that to `std::vector<movies_t> films(z);`.  As mentioned, the former is not valid C++.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulMcKenzie, but when I change ``movies_t films [z];`` to ``std::vector<movies_t> films(z);`` it gives error message:  ``In function 'int main()':
22:4: error: 'vector' is not a member of 'std'
22:24: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
22:33: error: 'films' was not declared in this scope
33:18: error: 'mystr' was not declared in this scope``

Comment: Minor point: get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `int z; z = getnumber();` to `int z = getnumber();`.

Comment: Thanks, @Alan Birtles. I used ``cin.ignore();`` to address this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Comment: Thanks, @Peter Becker. Lesson learned. Program changed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisMM: I have corrected the first mistake. Could you kindly help with the second mistake``movies_t films [z]; is also not valid in c++``?

Comment: @Krantz -- Did you `#include <vector>`?

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie. After adding ``#include <vector>``, it did not give that error, but still gives wrong results; now it gives: ``You have entered these movies:
 (0) (0)``. I have updated the code. Any thoughts? Sorry my stupid questions, I am coming from R, trying to use C++ to speed up my computations, so I might make basic mistakes in C++. Your understanding would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the input literally `"title1=q, year1=1, title2=w, year2=2"`? Are you trying to extract "q", "1", "w", and "2" from the aforementioned string?

Comment: Thanks, @David G. The program must print: ``q (1) w (2)``.  And the object ``films`` of the data structure ``movie_t`` must be assigned size dynamically; this and the other characteristics of the program are important for the actual program.

Comment: @Krantz -- First, you shouldn't change the code in the post.  If anything, add new code.  Second, you would have had a much easier time with a `std::map<std::string, int>`, where the `std::string` is the title, and then `int` is the year.

Comment: Thanks, @Blastfurnace. No, I am not going to delete after there are no more errors. It should help other people in the future. But if someone comments that this or that is incorrect, I feel I should correct the mistake. But if someone just writes the answer, then I will not correct any mistakes corrected in the answer.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? I guess the OP is asked to find the bug in given snippet.

Comment: Not hw at all, @Red.Wave. I am past hw's. As I said above, sorry my stupid questions, I am coming from R, trying to use C++ to speed up my computations, so I might make basic mistakes in C++. Your understanding would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Krantz As I am not convinced, I give you a short assignment: use this inputs: title1: Matrix year1:1999 title2: avatar year:2005. Please try this.

Comment: @Krantz did you run the test. I promise you'll regret not doing it.

Comment: @Red.Wave. In good faith I tested since you are insisting. The output is: ``You have entered these movies:
 (0)
999 (0)``.

Comment: Took me a while to setup a usefull input sequence. After running the program, without caring about prompts input this:`3`<2*press enter>`_1800`<press enter>`_matrix`<press enter>`_1999`<press enter>`_avatar`<press enter>`_2005`<2*press enter> then review the screen. it does tell you a lot.

Comment: Well. It terminates without performing its tasks. But you are not using it as expected. So, why should it behave as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function that gets the value after `=` in each token.

```
string getValue(string field) {
  auto pos = field.find('=');
  return field.substr(pos + 1, field.find(',') - pos - 1);
}
```

Then all you need to do is:

```
for (n = 0; n < z; n++) {
  string title, year;
  assert(cin >> title >> year);
  movies_t movie = {getValue(title), stoi(getValue(year))};
  films.push_back(movie);
}
```

To use `assert` you need `#include <cassert>` at the top.

Update:

You need to ignore spaces, so add this to your program:

```
struct ctype_ : std::ctype<char>
{
    static mask* make_table()
    {
        const mask* table = classic_table();
        static std::vector<mask> v(table, table + table_size);
        v[' '] &= ~space;
        v[','] |= space;
        return &v[0];
    }

    ctype_() : std::ctype<char>(make_table()) { }
};
```

And then do this just before the `for` loop:

```
cin.imbue(std::locale(cin.getloc(), new ctype_));
```

[And then it should work.](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7932fe9e11bc9eed)

2nd update:

```
for (n = 0; n < z; n++) {
  string title, year;
  cout << "Enter title: ";
  assert(cin >> title);
  cout << "Enter year: ";
  assert(cin >> year);
  movies_t movie = {getValue(title), stoi(getValue(year))};
  films[n] = movie;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @David G. But it is not working as you can see above; if I am doing correctly what your answer says. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd guess titles could have spaces so `cin >> title` would be incorrect?

Comment: Yes. That will not work and would change the philosophy of the program. It must be ``getline`` or similar.

Comment: @Krantz Does my update help at all?

Comment: Could you check the code under ``Code based on David G's answer``? Perhaps, there is something I am not doing well. But it still does not work.

Comment: @Krantz Put the `cin.imbue()` line just before the for loop.

Comment: Yes. I just did that, but still not working.

Comment: @Krantz Change `films.push_back(...)` to `films[n] = ...`

Comment: DONE: now works after ``films[n] = movie;``. Now, let's add ``Enter title: q
Enter year: 1
Enter title: w
Enter year: 2`` to get it working as in the desired output? THANKS.

Comment: @Krantz I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: How to make it print ``Enter title: `` and ``Enter year: `` as in the desired output? THANKS.

Comment: @Krantz See the update

Comment: DONE. THANKS A LOT.